# Error python: No module named analytics service object when using google analitycs API

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

So, I am trying to get the number of sessions for each traffic source from google analitycs for a website, but I came across with this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/mrgrj/PycharmProjects/google-api/get_sessions.py", line 3, in
>   
>       from analytics_service_object import initialize_service ImportError: No module named analytics_service_object

My code so far looks like this:

```
from analytics_service_object import initialize_service

def get_source_group(service, profile_id, start_date, end_date):
    ids = "ga:" + profile_id
    metrics = "ga:sessions"
    dimensions = "ga:channelGrouping"
    data = service.data().ga().get(
        ids=ids, start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date, metrics=metrics,
        dimensions=dimensions).execute()
    return dict(
        data["rows"] + [["total", data["totalsForAllResults"][metrics]]])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    service = initialize_service()
    profile_id = "your_profile_id"
    start_date = "2014-09-01"
    end_date = "2014-09-30"
    data = get_source_group(service, profile_id, start_date, end_date)
    for key, value in data.iteritems():
        print key, value
```

I have also installed the **Google API Python client library**:

```
pip install -U google-api-python-client
pip install python-gflags
```

What am I missing ?

As a mention, all of these work:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client import tools
```

Comment: You need to create this file, please refer [here](http://www.marinamele.com/use-google-analytics-api-with-python)

Comment: @Kobi , in the meantime I figured this out. Thanks. More, does anyone have any idea about how should I modify this, in order to get the number of visitors per day ?

Comment: dimension  ga:date   metric ga:sessions  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#cats=user,session    Good for testing :  https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/